# Mediawiki API call: Unrecognized parameter: gsrqiprofile

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I am attempting to use the related articles plugin on my mediawiki website, I have properly installed the most recent version and am running with the following configuration in the attached screenshot.

[image: Configuration of my mediawiki server]

However when I go to a page that should display the related articles section I don't see anything. So I dug into the networking tab of chrome and found the api call that it is making to the mediawiki api:

```
https://marblehorse.net/api.php?action=query&format=json&formatversion=2&origin=*&prop=pageimages&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=160&pilimit=3&generator=search&gsrsearch=morelike%3AStock&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=3&gsrqiprofile=classic_noboostlinks&uselang=content&smaxage=86400&maxage=86400
```

However when I went to that url I got the following error:

```
{"warnings":{"main":{"warnings":"Unrecognized parameter: gsrqiprofile."}},"batchcomplete":true}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Side Note:
I am using the following extensions

[image: List of the extensions that I am using]